# How can I stop Browser Crashes "Random" BSODs? Multi-year issue

Tags: linux, windows-10, browser, crash

**TL;DR:** Over multiple years, I have experienced BSOD's when running Windows (sometimes three or more times a day, sometimes a few times a week) along with browser tabs crashing in every browser inexplicably and seemingly at random (although more often with non-static pages) in both Windows and multiple flavours of Linux. It's driving me crazy and I feel like I've tried everything, so I'd like to know what to do next or if it seems like there's nothing to be done and I have to get a new computer.

**Specs**

ASUS GL-502V

Core i7 7700HQ
16GB RAM
1 * 128GB nVME SSD
1 * 500GB SATA SSD
GTX 1060
Windows 10 x64 (latest updates non-Insider)

**Longer version**

I first bought my computer in 2017 for an information security program I was going into at a technical school.

For the first 6 or so months, everything was great. I had no issues with running or installing anything, and there were no inexplicable errors. Then, I decided to replace Windows with Linux to help me get used to navigating the file system. I firstly installed Ubuntu with no issues, then decided to install Kali. There was an installation error when installing Kali on to the hard drive and since then every single Debian-based Linux installation has failed on the part regarding accessing the hard drive; this is regardless of which of the two hard drives were chosen.

Since then, I have been able to install arch-based Linuxes (Like Manjaro) and Windows.

Now, when I use any browser other than IE (have tried Chrome, Firefox, and derivatives of each on every operating system I have installed), tabs randomly crash. I could have the browser minimized and have every tab (10 or 11) except for one or two crash. I could be loading a Youtube video and the tab will crash, but refreshing restores it. I could then open up that same video in a new window with no problems, but the next day access the same video in the same browser and have to reload it a dozen or more times to get it to work.

I find it most commonly seems to happen on dynamic pages like Gmail, or any other pages that have dynamic content like Pluralsight, Cybrary, etc. But sometimes every tab will crash while I'm on a static page.

This has become increasingly frustrating when paired with the random BSODs I seem to encounter with Windows (only occasional freezing with Linux distros, but that could be normal). These BSODs often have to do with Memory_Management and Page faults and occur at seemingly random times. An example from this morning: I had Discord (no voice or video), Visual Studio code (with no application file open), and Brave browser (with a few tabs, one or two with dynamic content). Out of nowhere (moving my mouse) the system blue screened with Memory_Management as the reason.

I have tried literally everything I can think of short of re-flashing the BIOS and I'm not sure where to go next. This happens both on fresh OS installs and continuously thereafter.

Here's what I have tried:

- Clearing cache, cookies, etc. on all browsers.
- Have tried enabling / disabling antivirus during different activities (on Windows).
- Updating all drivers and firmware (including graphics card, BIOS, etc.) .
- Installing many, many web browsers and ensuring they're up to date.
- Installing multiple OS's including Windows 10 multiple times and many Linux distros.
- Zeroing out hard drives before re-installing operating systems.
- Removing page files completely (For BSODs)

I'm not really in a financial position to buy a new computer that would be any good for what I need / want to do (VMs, gaming, programming) so I'd like to make this computer last as long as I can, but because so much training, programming, and entertainment is on the web (and is sometimes unusable because no matter how many times I refresh it never stops crashing) it's very frustrating to use.

What am I missing? Could this be a hardware issue? How would I look into that?

Thank you for reading!

Edit:

I have tried all suggestions besides opening up the laptop to test the power supply, and the issues persist. I've been diligently recording the error messages from BSODs and browser messages and BSODs have been related to segmentation faults and PFN_LIST_CORRUPT, and browser errors are also related to segmentation faults. At this point I'm weighing the cost of replacing the RAM / SSDs on my laptop Vs leaving as is and getting a new machine.

Thanks for all your knowledge, y'all.

Comment: Ignore the others when they're going to groan and bear with me for a sec'... With that much RAM and an ongoing problem with BSODs that are most likely related to memory management and paging, in both Windows and Linux, if I were you, I'd try a simple thing: install ImDisk in Windows, create a 2GB RAM disk (AWE, non-dynamic, set all temp parameters to the RAM disk, cluster size at 64kb, no compression, NTFS file system), disable pagefile from System under Advanced / Performance, disable Fast Startup, and check if there are any more BSODs. Those were my 2 cents, born of experience...

Comment: You can find ImDisk here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/. Reboot after install.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestion! I've done this and I'll monitor going forward.

Answer (score 1):

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT errors can indicate a driver is doing something bad, which can be caused by failing hardware.

Disable hardware acceleration in your browser and see if crashes lessen.  If so, this implicates your graphics card or its drivers.

You can try to update or change your graphics card drivers, update/change graphics card firmware, underclock your graphics card to see if it remains stable, or remove it entirely.  If your graphics card has been used in mining it may have suffered wear and tear as a result.

If you remove your graphics card and the problems stay, I would suspect and troubleshoot things in this order:

- Check CPU/GPU/MB temperatures and make sure nothing is running too hot.
- Disable any antivirus you have installed temporarily and see if that's a contributing factor. (sounds like you already did this)
- Update UEFI firmware to latest version (sounds like you already did this)
- Check RAM (run Memtest86 or Windows Memory Diagnostic for a while)
- Power supply
- Motherboard

Comment: Thank you for the considered and helpful response! I have tried the antivirus toggling and firmware update as you mentioned. I did a run through Windows Memory Diagnostic and there were no reported issues.

It is a laptop so it wouldn't surprise me if heat was an issue, but It doesn't seem to have more problems when under load (gaming, running VMs, etc.); I'll look into temperatures though!

Any suggestions on checking the power supply or motherboard on a laptop? 

Thanks again!